# How do I properly store video embed codes in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

When storing video embed codes submitted by users, I use mysql_real_escape_string() to make sure nothing will harm my database. That's really messing with the embed code too, obviously. I'd like to retrieve the embed codes again in the exact way they were submitted. Is it possible to do this safely?

While I'm very much open to alternative solutions to achieve the same goal, I'd rather not store just the video ID because that might lead to confusion when there are multiple video hosting services involved.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**Edit:** The embed code passes through a hidden input using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), then gets mysql_real_escape_string()'d when it is inserted into the database. Once submitted, certain parts of the code appear [triple slashed](http://pastie.org/3232900), breaking it.

Comment: The escaping is only used when inserting to the database. The data isn't stored escaped, nor is it escaped when you retrieve it.

Comment: Ah, I had the data in a hidden field before submission. The HTML code from the embed didn't fit into the input's value field all that well... I should try fixing that, sorry!

Comment: I used htmlspecialchars() to store the data in the hidden input before submission, which worked great. After submission using mysql_real_escape_string() the embed codes appears modified in phpMyAdmin. Same thing when retrieving it: http://pastie.org/3232900 .

Comment: You are double escaping. You probably use `mysql_real_escape`twice on the string...

Comment: I think htmlspecialchars() is also escaping the embed code. When I insert stripslashes(hidden-input-data-which-was-htmlspecialchars'd) directly, I get valid data in my database (no slashes). If I add mysql_real_escape() around the stripslashes() things no longer work, though (1 slash).

Comment: No, htmlspecialchars() doesn't escape. And I don't think you should store it using htmlspecialchars(), that's something you can do on the output just before you print it to the user's screen. You probably have magic quotes enabled - this is bad as it isn't as secure as mysql_real_escape_string(). Find it, disable it, and use mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Magic quotes was enabled, and put slashes on the string when it was placed in a hidden input field from a previous POST form, then put another pair of slashes on when it was submitted to the DB. Solution: stripslashes() during the inputfield value echo AND during the submission. Thank you for your help.